# Java Service Wrapper System tray icon issue

Tags: java, windows-services, system-tray, java-service-wrapper

Am using Java Service Wrapper (tanuki) to create a Windows Service on top of my java application. When the service is running, I wanted to create an icon in System tray to notify the user the service is running (and likewise a different icon to show service is stopped)

```
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=TRUE
wrapper.ntservice.hide_console=FALSE
```

I have set the above two properties which allows the service to interact with the desktop, but in-spite of this when I start my service, the tray icon does not show up (service starts up successfully). Can anyone tell me what might be happening here?

Am java 1.6 and JSW 35.7 (modified for 64 bit)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks
K

Answer (score 0):

What version of Windows are you using.  Microsoft changed the way Services work in Windows Vista and Server 2008 so that Services now run on their own desktop.  This makes it impossible for the service to interact directly with the desktop any longer.

Please see the note on the following page:

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-ntservice-interactive.html

Cheers,
Leif

Comment: Leif, Am on Windows 7. I did read the page you mentioned in your comment. The page did not seem to say that tray icon is impossible. From what I can understand it seems like if you set those two properties, they are suggesting we should be able to see the tray icon. Am wondering what else needs to be done.